How can such a complex knot be implemented using TikZ?

I’ve been reading Adams’ knot theory book recently, and it contains many knot diagrams. I’ve already managed to draw many of them using hobby package, by generating curves through plotting points, but this method is more suitable for simpler and smaller diagrams. How should I implement this particular diagram? The points I want to learn are: first, how to draw the ellipsis in the diagram; second, for knots with repeated similar structures, is there a more concise way to draw them?

The spath3 library  help here. 1. Create the paths. 2. Let the library find the intersections and adjust the paths accordingly. 3. Draw the adjusted paths. The sublibrary knots can make this easier with its knot environment and \strand command. The dots could be just \dots in a node or three circles. The repeated stuff might not be as easy, depends on your paths. Do you know the paths and their possible customizations?

To add, if you have little to no experience with Tikz, I suggest: 1. (re)read and try the tutorials in https://tikz.dev . 2. After that try a simplified version of the intended diagram, i.e. put a few named nodes and draw straight connections between them. This opens the door to further stepwise refinement.

You could also draw the know separately (the five "knotty" parts with the three dots are essentially the same) and create a \pic from this, then connect five instances of this \pic.

It's not really so complex.
You can set up five nodes for the a_i, and then draw the knot with regular crossings at each of the a_i. If you use the knots library to draw the path of the knot, you can adjust the crossing at the "halfway" loop between the a_3 and -a_3.
After that, use Jasper Habicht's suggestion of a \pic to place the "dotty" parts on top of the nodes. The \pic itself can use the same trick: the knots library with two strands, and a node on top of that with the "...".
Since some of the nodes are positive and some negative, the \pic will need to take an argument. I wrote the crossing numbers directly into the argument.
    \documentclass[standalone]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{knots,hobby,fit}
    \usepackage[outline]{contour}
     \newcommand{\fat}[1]{\contour{black}{#1}}
     
     \begin{document}
      
    \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
    
      \tikzset{ pics/nodepic/.style 2 args={code={
                 \node[fill=white,inner sep=0pt,fit={(-0.3,-0.15) (1.5,0.15)}] (#1) {};
                 \begin{knot}[end tolerance=0mm,clip width=1.2mm,
                           flip crossing/.list={#2}
                        ]
                        \strand[thick] plot [smooth] coordinates {
              (-0.3,-0.15) (0, 0.15) (0.3,0) (0.9,-0.15) (1.5,0.15) % un
            };
            \strand[thick] plot [smooth] coordinates {
              (-0.3,0.15) (0, -0.15) (0.3,0) (0.9,0.15) (1.5,-0.15) %nu
            };
          \end{knot}
          \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum height=5mm,fill=white,label=below:{$#1$}, anchor=west] at (0.6,0) {\fat{\ldots}};
        }
      }
    }
    
% identify the locations of the "nodes"
    \coordinate (ma1) at (0,0); % -a1
    \coordinate (a2) at (3,5); % a2
    \coordinate (ma3) at (6,0); % -a3
    \coordinate (a3) at (9,0); % a3
    \coordinate (ma2) at (12,5); % -a2
    
    \coordinate (h2) at (7.5,5); % halfway point

% create "dummy" nodes -- this section will define a rectangular named node at each of the a_i
    \pic at (ma1) {nodepic={-a_1}{}};
    \pic at (a2) {nodepic={a_2}{}};
    \pic at (ma2) {nodepic={-a_2}{}};
    \pic at (a3) {nodepic={a_3}{}};
    \pic at (ma3) {nodepic={-a_3}{}};
    

% the main knot: for each of the a_i, if we enter to the north, we leave to the south, and vice versa. we follow the knot around.

    \begin{knot}[end tolerance=1mm,flip crossing/.list={6},
      % draft mode=crossings, % turn this on to find out which crossing to flip for the "halfway point" node
      consider self intersections=true,clip width=3mm,]
      \strand[draw, blue]
      (-a_1.north west)
    .. ([shift=({0,4})]-a_1.center) % guide the curve
    ..  (a_2.north west) -- (a_2.south east)
    ..  (-a_3.north west) -- (-a_3.south east) 
    .. (a_3.south west) -- (a_3.north east)
    .. (-a_2.south west) -- (-a_2.north east)
    .. ([shift=({0.5,0})]-a_2.east)..([shift=({0,-6})]-a_2.center) % guide the curve
    .. (-a_1.south west) -- (-a_1.north east)
    .. (a_2.south west) -- (a_2.north east)
    .. (h2) % halfway point
    .. (-a_2.north west) -- (-a_2.south east)
    ..([shift=({-1,-4})]-a_2.south east) % guide the curve
    .. (a_3.south east) -- (a_3.north west)
    -- ([shift=({0.2,0.5})]h2) ..([shift=({-0.2,0.5})]h2) % loop over halfway point
    -- (-a_3.north east) -- (-a_3.south west)
    .. (-a_1.south east) -- (-a_1.north west)
    ;
    \end{knot}
    
% draw in the "knotty" parts on top. the second argument is the list of crossings that must be flipped -- (1,3) for a "negative" node, (2) for a positive node
    \draw pic at (ma1) {nodepic={-a_1}{1,3}};
    \draw pic at (a2) {nodepic={a_2}{2}};
    \draw pic at (ma2) {nodepic={-a_2}{1,3}};
    \draw pic at (a3) {nodepic={a_3}{2}};
    \draw pic at (ma3) {nodepic={-a_3}{1,3}};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}


Certainly it's less smooth and elegant than the original, but I think it has all the features. The underbraces could be added in as another node.
